# WPF Binding ZoomLevel and Center in BingMaps control

Tags: c#, xaml

I need help how make binding to ZoomLevel Property and Center Property?
I was able to make a binding on PushPins but ZoomLevel and Center I don't know how bind
Thank you!

```
<UserControl x:Class="AppGST.BingMaps"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppGST"
          xmlns:map="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="628" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MapTemplate">
        <map:Pushpin map:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
        <map:Map Height="628" 
                   CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource Key}"
                   ZoomLevel="2"
                   Mode="Road"
                   Name="WorldMap">

            <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PinsLocations}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MapTemplate}"/>
            </map:Map>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel Class

```
public class BingMapsViewModel : ObserverableObject, IPageViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<MapModel> _pinsLocations;

    public ObservableCollection<MapModel> PinsLocations
    {
        get { return _pinsLocations; }
        set
        {
            _pinsLocations= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
    public BingMapsViewModel()
    {
        GSTService.GetRecentLocationDataForGST((o, ea) =>
        {
            GSTLocations = new ObservableCollection<MapModel>(ea.Locations);
        });
    }
}

public class GSTService
{
    public static void GetRecentLocationDataForGST(EventHandler<GSTLocationsEventArgs> callback)
    {
        List<MapModel> data = new List<MapModel>();
        data.Add(new MapModel { Location = new Location(32.021944, 34.757732), ZoomLevel = 18 });
        data.Add(new MapModel { Location = new Location(43.273558, 76.914842), ZoomLevel = 18 });
        data.Add(new MapModel { Location = new Location(55.753215, 37.622504), ZoomLevel = 18 });
        callback(null, new GSTLocationsEventArgs(data));
    }
}

public class GSTLocationsEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public List<MapModel> Locations { get; set; }
    public GSTLocationsEventArgs(List<MapModel>locations)
    {
        Locations = locations;
    }
}
```

Model
    public class MapModel : ObserverableObject 
    {
        private Location _location;
        private double_zoomLevel;

```
    public double ZoomLevel { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This method worked for me.
I was writing a WPF application with .NET Framework 4.5, Prism v4.0.30319, and Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF v1.0.0.0

In the View's XAML file I added bound "Center" and "ZoomLevel" properties

```
<map:Map 
   Height="628" 
   CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource Key}"
   Center="{Binding MapCenter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
   ZoomLevel="{Binding MapZoomLevel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
   Mode="Road"
   Name="WorldMap"
>
</map:Map>
```

In the ViewModel's C# file

Because I was using Prism, by assembly references were

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using Prism.Events;
    using Prism.Commands;
    using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;   
    using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Core;
```

I added some members to the class member list

```
        private Double                                  m_Double_ZoomLevel = 6.0;
        private String                                  m_String_MapCenter = null;
        private const Int32                             m_c_Int32_ZoomLevel_Minimum = 1;
        private const Int32                             m_c_Int32_ZoomLevel_Maximum = 20;
```

I added to the class constructor code to set the map center and zoom level to previously saved values (or default values if no saved ones are available)

```
            m_String_MapCenter = SavedMapCenter( );
            if( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( m_String_MapCenter))
            {
                m_String_MapCenter = "51.5,0";
            }

            m_Double_ZoomLevel = SavedZoomLevel( );
            if( ( m_Double_ZoomLevel < m_c_Int32_ZoomLevel_Minimum) || ( m_Double_ZoomLevel > m_c_Int32_ZoomLevel_Maximum))
            {
                m_Double_ZoomLevel = 6;
            }
```

I also added to the constructor a couple of Prism delegate commands to manipulate the ZoomLevel programatically

```
            CommandZoomOut = new DelegateCommand( ZoomOut);
            CommandZoomIn = new DelegateCommand( ZoomIn);
```

I added to the class a MapZoomLevel Property

```
        public Double MapZoomLevel
        { 
            get
            {
                return m_Double_ZoomLevel; 
            }

            set
            {

                if
                (
                    ( ( Double)( value) >= m_c_Int32_ZoomLevel_Minimum)
                &&  ( ( Double)( value) <= m_c_Int32_ZoomLevel_Maximum)
                &&  ( m_Double_ZoomLevel != ( Double)( value))
                )
                {
                    m_Double_ZoomLevel = ( Double)( value);
                    RaisePropertyChanged( "MapZoomLevel");//NOTE this is a Prism event 
                }
            }
```

I added to the class a MapCenter Property

```
        public String MapCenter
        {
            get 
            { 
                return m_String_MapCenter; 
            }

            set 
            { 
                if( m_String_MapCenter != ( String)( value))
                {
                    m_String_MapCenter = ( String)( value);
                    RaisePropertyChanged( "MapCenter");//NOTE this is a Prism event
                }
            }
        }
```

I defined the ZoomIn and ZoomOut commands as per the Prism DelegateCommand definition

```
        public DelegateCommand CommandZoomOut
        { 
            get; 
            set;

        }//public DelegateCommand CommandViewNineTrackTapes

        public DelegateCommand CommandZoomIn
        { 
            get; 
            set;

        }//public DelegateCommand CommandZoomIn


        private void ZoomOut( )
        {
            if( ZoomLevel > m_c_Int32_ZoomLevel_Minimum)
            {
                ZoomLevel = ZoomLevel - 1;
                SaveZoomLevel( ZoomLevel);
            }
        }

        private void ZoomIn( )
        {
            if( ZoomLevel < m_c_Int32_ZoomLevel_Maximum)
            {
                ZoomLevel = ZoomLevel + 1;
                SaveZoomLevel( ZoomLevel);
            }
        }
```

And that was it.